# What C# feature is this?

Tags: c#-9.0

In my C# application (which uses C# 9) I had a line of code like this:

```
var filterCallback = new HitTestFilterCallback(
    el => el is Path s && s.DataContext is IShape shp ?
        HitTestFilterBehavior.Continue : HitTestFilterBehavior.ContinueSkipSelf);
```

Resharper suggested I "merge sequential checks".  It rewrote the code to this

```
        var filterCallback = new HitTestFilterCallback(
            el => el is Path {DataContext: IShape shp}
                ?
                HitTestFilterBehavior.Continue : HitTestFilterBehavior.ContinueSkipSelf);
```

I am interested in the bit that lets me write

```
{DataContext: IShape shp}
```

in place of

```
s.DataContext is IShape shp
```

Is there a specific technical language name for this feature?   I want to read up on it to understand it better but I don't even know what to call it.  I tried looking under "pattern matching" and reading about the "is" keyword but don't see anything that looks like it?

Comment: As GSerg wrote, it is a "pattern"... I'll say it is quite unreadable and it will take me many months to get used to it... Fortunately where I work no one knows about it :-)

Comment: And I'm not even able to FIND the documentation about the use of `:` to mean "is"

Comment: I initially commented that it is a [switch expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression) with a recursive pattern. It isn't (because there is no `switch` keyword), but it is type matching with a recursive pattern, and I am failing to find an example or even a mention of the recursive pattern outside of the context of the switch expression.

Comment: Well in that case I'm feeling a little bit better about not being able to find it myself.  Resharper is scary good, sometimes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature is called "recursive patterns". In particular it is using a "property pattern" as part of a "recursive pattern".

You can find the proposal document here: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/csharp-8.0/patterns.md

You can find a more informal blog post about it here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/do-more-with-patterns-in-c-8-0/